# Why is my amazon developer portal's security profile invalidated?

Tags: ios, login-with-amazon

I know this question is not much related to stackoverflow but I'd like to ask it anyway in case someone else has had this problem.

I'm having a problem with amazon developer portal's security profiles. I've created a profile, a while ago, and now I want to add an iOS API Key to it. I type the name and bundle id and proceed to add it but am greeted with an error page telling me that my security profile is invalid.

My question is, why would a security profile be invalidated? And how come since it's invalid, its API Keys are still working?

P.S. I've tried creating a new security profile and adding an iOS API Key to it and it works. But I don't want to have to add all the API Keys I already have for Web/Android/iOS to the new security profile and deploy new builds for all my apps.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted Amazon developer support and it turns out they recently introduced a limit on the number of API Keys that can be created under one security profile. No more than 10 API Keys are allowed all together (Website, Android, iOS) for a security profile.